# Time difference in python not working for some dates

Tags: python, datetime

I have this function to count difference between two timestamps in seconds.

```
def diffdates(d1, d2):
  diff =  (time.mktime(time.strptime(d2,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")) -
           time.mktime(time.strptime(d1, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")))
  pprint(d2)
  pprint(d1)
  pprint(diff)
  return diff

diffdates(diffdates('2016-10-11T11:10:00','2016-10-11T16:00:00')
```

When I call it with given parameters, I expect the result to be

```
4*3600-10*60 = 13800
```

but I get

```
17400 = 5*3600 - 10*60
```

I was checking, if I have some problem with the formatting strings in documentation, but I can not find any. Also there is no changes in time like summer/winter time in that date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your math is wrong.  The delta between 16:00 and 11:10 is 4 hours 50 minutes.  Your computation of `4*3600-10*60` is suggesting 3 hours 50 minutes.  You're off by an hour.

`16:00` is `60*16` minutes into the day: `960`

`11:10` is `60*11+10` minutes into the day `670`

`960 - 670` is `290` minutes

`290 minutes * 60` is `17400` seconds.